# Transform cURL command to Python Requests command

Tags: python, django, ssl, curl, python-requests

I'm new with cURL and Requests and I have a doubt on how I can transform a cURL petition to a Requests command in Python.

Looking at Apache Stratos documentation [Doc Page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/STRATOS/4.1.x+Session+Authentication+via+REST+API) to perform a login against the server, in cURL you use:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k -v -u admin:admin https://localhost:9443/api/session
```

And it works on the terminal. Now, I want to do the same on my Django website and to transform the curl URL to python code and use the module "requests" I don't know how pass the user and pass info on the petition.

The code that I have now it's:

```
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
data = {}
req = requests.post('https://localhost:9443/api/session', headers=headers, params=data)
```

But I don't know how pass the user and password so I tried this ([Requests Python Login Tutorial](https://kazuar.github.io/scraping-tutorial/))

```
data = {"username":"admin","password":"admin"}
```

But I get a certificate error from server:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 385, in send raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

So, I'm sending correctly the user and password? How I can solve the certificate error?

Thanks and regards

Comment: You're on localhost.  Is it absolutely critical to use SSL?  Try `http://localhost:9443/api/session` .  Python requests is actually very smooth dealing with SSL, but a valid SSL cert on localhost seems unlikely.

Comment: Yes, all URL's on the doc page uses Https and when you access to the login page on Firefox, you need to add a security exception to see the page.

Comment: Looks like you've got two answers to choose from :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [turn off SSL cert verification](http://docs.python-requests.org/) with the `verify` flag, and use [basic authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) by specifying `auth`.

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

req = requests.post('https://localhost:9443/api/session', headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'admin'), verify=False)
```

See the [requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/) for more info.

Comment: Yes, I found it after try @Sam answer. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using your localhost which almost certainly doesn't have a valid certificate.

For testing purposes disable ssl verification (it is still encrypted just not verifying certificate)

```
req = requests.post('https://localhost:9443/api/session', headers=headers, params=data, verify=False)
```

Comment: `verify=False`   Nice.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this flag!

Answer (score 0):

After the @Sam solution and looking on the [Requests Auth Doc Page](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/) I found the solution:

The Python Resquest code it's:

```
requests.get('https://localhost:9443/api/session', headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'admin'), verify=False)
```

The "params" field it's not needed.

And then:

```
u'{"Success":{ "sessionId": "547D78FD4966DDBE21AEFDAECE909DEC"}}'
```

Hope it helps someone!